# Read Forms from BAR file - Flowable in code -

Tags: forms, flowable

I need an example of usign FormEngine. To be more especific....
I'm executing code below - but there’s no forms found in my BAR file :(
The BAR file was exported from Flowable Modeler and it contains one form and one process and app. Maybe there's other way to deploy and obtain forms...?

```java
RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
FormRepositoryService formRepositoryService =  formEngine.getFormRepositoryService();
File file = new File(path);


ZipInputStream inputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
String idDeployParent = repositoryService.createDeployment()
                                         .name(file.getName())
                                         .addZipInputStream(inputStream)
                                         .deploy()
                                         .getId();

DeploymentEntity deploymentEntity = (DeploymentEntity) repositoryService.createDeploymentQuery().list().get(0);

formRepositoryService.createDeployment()
                     .name(file.getName())
                     .parentDeploymentId(idDeployParent)
                     .deploy();

System.out.println(" FORMS FOUND: " + formRepositoryService.createFormDefinitionQuery().list().size());
```

Comment: Which version of Flowable are you using? If you unpackage the bar file (rename it to end with .zip) does it contain the form?

Comment: the latest version -6.4.1 - . Yes, it contain the .form file , but I can't get it and read

Comment: I can read the name of every file into the BAR file using this(view code) but not into the form file

https://codeshare.io/5wYzvp

Comment: @Filip any idea? thanks in advice